# C# Changing the cursor's clicking/pointing position?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

So the default cursor is the "Arrow" cursor and the top-left of the arrow (where the point is) is the part that clicks or interacts with other controls.  How can I change the pointing part to say the tail of the arrow?

What I have is a custom cursor (a bitmap image) which is a circle at 16x16 size and I want the very center of it to be the pointer.  I have another custom arrow-like cursor that points downward-left also 16x16 and I want the bottom-left corner of the cursor to be the pointer.  I think there's a property in the cursor class for this but I'm not sure what it's called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually specified in the `CUR` [file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29).

> The CUR file format is an almost identical image file format for
>   non-animated cursors in Microsoft Windows. The only differences
>   between these two file formats are the bytes used to identify them and
>   the addition of a hotspot in the CUR format header; the hotspot is
>   defined as the pixel offset (in x,y coordinates) from the top-left
>   corner of the cursor image where the user is actually pointing the
>   mouse.

Programs that can edit `CUR` files generally allow you to specify the hot spot. More information can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133078/how-do-you-set-hotspot-co-ordinates-on-a-windows-cursor-generated-from-an-icon-fi).

Comment: I guess I should've specified that what I have is a bitmap (png) and not a cursor file.  Is there any way to do this with a bitmap?

Comment: @Jack - Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550918/change-cursor-hotspot-in-winforms-net) is closer to what you need?

Answer (score 1):

What you want **can't be done** through code. I wanted do the same thing but it's not possible.
In fact, the [Cursor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx) has a property called HotSpot, which is the point that you want change. However this property is readonly.
The only way to change this is at file loading (on a .cur file, I suggest you using Paint .net with Cursor and icons plugin (search over the web) to edit cursor). An important thing: the cursor must be a file and not a resource or things like that (must be a file on the file system) to load it. Remember it, I had bad times testing in other ways.

The idea that I have in mind is: edit cursor file just when you need to change the hotspot, however this require for you writing an api that allows you to change the hotspot on a cursor file. I obviusly don't know how this file is built so you must continue from here.

Hope this was useful

Comment: Doesn't this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550918/change-cursor-hotspot-in-winforms-net) or Rick's tutorial create a Cursor from a Bitmap during runtime (i.e. through code)?

Comment: Well you can create a bitmap through code, what I didn't know is that you can create a sort of handle to that cursor without it being a file (I thought you must save it on the file system even if you create it at runtime), I read it there on some other question, sorry for that. However you **have** to rebuild the whole cursor to change its hotspot, that's the important thing that I wanted show to him